# How to make docpad @document collection sort descending by timestamp

Tags: file, sorting, docpad

working on my docpad blog, in testing I see sorting is descending by the title, but most blogs are sorted ascending.

How would you suggest solving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In docpad.coffee I added

```
posts: ->   @getCollection('documents').findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:'blog'},[timestamp:-1])
```

and then I add a timestamp to all the markdown files.

Answer (score 0):

There are *several* ways to do this. In fact you can order it by name, extension, date etc.

Since you want to have it sorted by date you need to add a `date` meta entry to your file:

```
---
title: Post name
layout: post
date: 2013-09-26
---
Post content blah blah blah.
```

The focus is on the `date` entry, it's format is `YEAR-MONTH-DAY`.

Then you can have the following:

```
@getCollection('html').findAllLive({relativeOutDirPath:'posts'},[{date:-1}])
```

The important part being `[{date:-1}]`. That would put the latest posts first, if you want it the other way around make it just a one without the `-`: `[{date:1}]`

Hope that helps!

Oh BTW, that example I provided is from a more complex query: https://github.com/Greduan/eduantech.docpad/blob/d5e97638331ab24730d3331b9fbcc30cf1d46dcc/docpad.coffee#L45-L49

Comment: Hi, I already figured it out with the timestamp - I was already sorting by date, but then I had multiple posts per date so had to sort by timestamp. However your complex query there interests me - what does the .on 'add', (model) etc. etc. stuff do? Is it a way to put all posts from a particular day in its own url? so I can do /posts/2013-09-09 for example?

Comment: Yes that's it pretty much. I automatically add the layout of `post`, I change it's URL so that it's nicely formatted like this: `www.website.com/2013/07/post-name`. Remember to accept your answer so that this question is marked fixed. :)

Comment: @user254694 Forgot to mention you. :)